# launch firefox full screen on boot - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome

I know there is already questions about this topic, however all the solution are about a kiosk mode, if I only want to launch firefox (or chrome) in full screen with a certain url regardless of user permissions and whatever, how will I proceed?
I can already open firefox with the "startup Applications" with the command "firefox [URL]" but not in full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using an add-on like [Auto FullScreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/autofullscreen/) by tazeat for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative add-on, which also works (tested in Firefox ESR under Ubuntu 22.04.1):
[Auto Fullscreen by insiderser](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/i-auto-fullscreen/)
Description:
"This is a fork of Auto Fullscreen add-on by tazeat. The difference is that this add-on makes all windows fullscreen, while the one by tazeat makes only the initial window fullscreen. This is useful if you like to open tabs in separate windows."